# Kendo grid with default Columns

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to show to users subset of columns and allow them to add extra columns if needed. I am struggling to load only subset of columns on load. Please find the code below I have done.

```
 <kendo-grid k-options="vm.mainGridOptions"
    k-columns="vm.mainGridColumns"
    k-sortable="true"
    k-filterable="{mode: 'row'}"
    k-column-menu="true"
    k-serverFiltering="false"
    k-pageSize="10"
    k-pageable="{ pageSizes: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100] }"> </kendo-grid>
```

Controller code

```
var mainGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: { read: mainGridReadEventHandler, cache: true },
        serverFiltering: false,
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        schema: {
            data: 'data',
            total: 'total',
            model: {
                fields: {
                    customerName: { type: "string" },
                    serviceAccountStatus: { type: "string" },
                    customerNumber: { type: "string" },
                    serviceType: { type: "string" },
                    utilityAccountNumber: { type: "string" },
                    serviceAddress: { type: "string" },
                    billingAccountNumber: { type: "string" },
                    utility: { type: "string" },
                    phoneNumber: { type: "string" },
                    email: { type: "string" }

                }
            }

        }
    });

vm.mainGridColumns = [
        {
            field: "customerName",
            title: "Name",
            template:
                "<a ui-sref='resiservice.account-search.customer-details({ customerId:${customerId}, serviceAccountId:${serviceAccountId} })'>${customerName}</a>"
        },
        {
            field: "serviceAccountStatus",
            title: "Status"
        },
        {
            field: "customerNumber",
            title: "NAP Customer #"
        },
        {
            field: "serviceType",
            title: "Commodity"
        },
        {
            field: "utilityAccountNumber",
            title: "Utility/Account #"
        },
        {
            field: "serviceAddress",
            title: "Service Address"
        },
        {
            field: "billingAccountNumber",
            title: "NAP Account #"
        },
        {
            field: "utility",
            title: "Utility"
        },
        {
            field: "phoneNumber",
            title: "Phone #"
        },
        {
            field: "email",
            title: "Email Address"
        }
    ];
```

[Currently columns list coming like this first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1cD0.jpg)

[And i want to achive like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiF1I.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [columns.hidden property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.hidden) to hide a column, i.e.

```
    {
        field: "utility",
        title: "Utility",
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        field: "phoneNumber",
        title: "Phone #",
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        field: "email",
        title: "Email Address",
        hidden: true
    }
```

For example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/EzuFO

The column is still visible on the list of columns in menu.

Comment: Dawid, I also have another question. is it possible to keep all the column selection at single location. may be some button which will use to hide and show columns? if you want i can add another question for this.

Comment: Here's how I implement a single point for the hide/show column menu.  it's pretty complicated, though and looks *much* better in my project with all the proper styling, but it should get you going: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/AvAqE  Click the tiny button in the top-left corner of the grid toolbar to see it in action.  Link to my original answer on the Telerik forums with some explanation: http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-column-menu-only-in-one-column#6d94PE5530C9OpC4n5JhXA

Comment: @TrusharTandel - I was happy to help. If my answer addressed your problem and was helpful please mark it as accepted and upvote. Regarding your second question I think that next time you should consider asking another question so that it is easy to find for anyone who has the same problem. At the same time Stephen's answer could be upvoted and added to his score.

Comment: @Dawid, I have accepted the answer but when i click to upvote, it's showing me "Thanks for the feedback! votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". please let me know what should i do to upvote. (i am new to adding question too) bare with me.

Comment: @Dawid did you get vote for above answer ?  i am still getting same message.